# Getting error in the editor MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found. what is that meaning? and how to resolve it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GapRangeAttribute : PropertyAttribute
{
    public float minRange;
    public float maxRange;
    public float sensitivity;

    public GapRangeAttribute(float minRange, float maxRange, float sensitivity)
    {
        this.minRange = minRange;
        this.maxRange = maxRange;
        this.sensitivity = sensitivity;
    }
}
```

and this

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(GapRangeAttribute))]
public class GapRangeDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    float minRange;
    float maxRange;
    float sensitivity;

    public GapRangeDrawer(float minRange, float maxRange, float sensitivity)
    {
        this.minRange = minRange;
        this.maxRange = maxRange;
        this.sensitivity = sensitivity;
    }

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        if (property.propertyType == SerializedPropertyType.Float)
        {
            EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);
            EditorGUI.Slider(position, property, minRange, maxRange, label);
            property.floatValue = RoundValue(property.floatValue);
            EditorGUI.EndProperty();
        }
        else
        {
            EditorGUI.LabelField(position, label.text, "Use [GapRangeDrawer] with float values only!");
        }
    }

    private float RoundValue(float value)
    {
        return Mathf.Round(value / sensitivity) * sensitivity;
    }
}
```

and using it in mono script:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cubePrefab;
    public LayerMask terrainLayer;
    [GapRange(0, 100, 0.1f)]
    public float gap = 0f;
```

and using the gap variable in some places in the mono script.
i'm not getting any errors in the visual studio only in the editor.

MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type GapRangeDrawer

Comment: It wants you to add a default (ie. parameterless) constructor.  eg. `public GapRangeDrawer() {  }`  This is because unity is spawning the class, and will only use the parameterless constructor (since it wouldn't know what the params are).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity wants to create an instance of `GapRangeDrawer` but does not know how to use your constructor, i.e., which values to pass as argument.

Add it a constructor with no parameters, i.e., a so called default constructor.

```cs
public GapRangeDrawer()
    : this(0, 100, 0.1f) // pass default values to the other constructor
{
}
```

You can still use the constructor with 3 parameters in your code.

Comment: In general you want to have constructors for the `GapRangeAttribute`, **NOT** for the `GapRangeDrawer`! Unity itself creates the instances of `PropertyDrawer` (and `Editor`) and you never want to have your own constructors for them (just like also for `MonoBehaviour` and `ScriptableObject`)